# Why does console show an HTML element as a plain object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mutation-observers, htmlelements

Normally, when I query the DOM

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    {{item}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

like this

```
var targetNode = document.querySelector('mat-nav-list');
console.log(targetNode)
```

the output is an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<mat-nav-list _ngcontent-c3="" class="mat-nav-list mat-list-base" role="navigation">
</mat-list-item></mat-nav-list>
```

But when I use stackblitz to create a new Angular App and do the same I get the "HTMLElement" object of Mat-list that looks like a plain object. Is there something wrong with the way I'm using MutationObserver?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vz9gn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @wOxxOm, I tried adding tree but I just gives me the parent elements which are also attributes.

Is there a was to get mutation to see an "*ngFor loop" element list as a childList and not an attribute?

Comment: Not 100% sure here, but it sounds like you might be just getting confused on the difference between how normal dev tools displays targetNode versus how Stackblitz does? Chrome for example will show an HTMLElement as if it was HTML so that you can explore the structure more easily. But it's still an HTMLElement just the same. What does console.log(targetNode instanceof HTMLElement); display?

Comment: You are right @TylerChurch. I was confused with how chrome and Stackblitz display  target Nodes. Thanks